# rsync error on Vagrant up with Centos 7

Tags: centos, vagrant, rsync, centos7

I want to move to a virtualbox environment on my new laptop so wanted to test out vagrant. However I havent been able to get past Vagrant up without one error after another, I have got through a number of errors and now im stuck.

Rsync is always failing to exec ssh (full error below)

- Platform Windows 7 pro SP1.
- Cygwin installed with Rsync.
- Vagrant installed
- Virtualbox installed
- Putty.exe on my desktop.
- Git installed.

rsync and putty added to end of sytstem path like

> ..;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Users\paul\Desktop\putty.exe;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd

Vagrant file consists of (including a windows/rsync error fix)

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"] = ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"].to_s + " cygwin"
 end
```

I also tried changing line 43 in C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.6.X\plugins\synced_folders\rsync\helper.rb to hostpath = "/cygdrive" + Vagrant::Util::Platform.cygwin_path(hostpath)

instead of putting it in the vagrant file.

Still I cant get rsync to work. Im not even sure why it needs to do this on 'up' anyway.

im running vagrant up from cmd here is the full output.

```
 C:\Users\paul\Projects\gettingStarted-centos7>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: No guest additions were detected on the base box for this VM! Guest

    default: additions are required for forwarded ports, shared folders, host on
ly
    default: networking, and more. If SSH fails on this machine, please install
    default: the guest additions and repackage the box to continue.
    default:
    default: This is not an error message; everything may continue to work prope
rly,
    default: in which case you may ignore this message.
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/c/Users/paul/Projects/gettingStarted-cen
tos7/ => /home/vagrant/sync
There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /cygdrive/c/Users/paul/Projects/gettingStarted-centos7/
Guest path: /home/vagrant/sync
Command: rsync --verbose --archive --delete -z --copy-links --chmod=ugo=rwX --no
-perms --no-owner --no-group --rsync-path sudo rsync -e ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHos
tKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=true -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i 'C:/Us
ers/paul/Projects/gettingStarted-centos7/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/pr
ivate_key' --exclude .vagrant/ /cygdrive/c/Users/paul/Projects/gettingStarted-ce
ntos7/ vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/sync
Error: rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=
3.1.1]
```

Comment: you can first use the plugin `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest` and reboot your machine to get rid of the guest addition message. can you also make sure ssh is installed on your system ?

Comment: You were right, even though SSH was installed via cygwin it wasnt configured to run. I have done that now and its fine :-)

Comment: good, making an answer so question can be marked resolved

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the blocking point, ssh is not installed or not configured to run (as confirmed by the ops) so it throws the error (also commented on [github issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3230#issuecomment-54714726))

As a side note, it can be good to install the [vagrant vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) so you'll get rid of the warnings. `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest` will take care of installing the vbguest, shared folder will work better with the guest additions.

Comment: I used the same solution on Ubuntu host. As this is not win7 related, this "tag" could be removed from the title.